# How to show and hide previous and new item by time interval Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with big quantity of data, and all data are not fering in screen, was decided to change data depends of time interval. When my page is load in array i received **18 items**, which i put in to div's.

So i need show in page first **8 items**, after 10 second, another **8 items**, and in the end show **2 items** (because i have only *18 items*.).
So i create script which show one by one div's, but i need show 8 in 10 second

```js
var current = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    var divs = $(".cards").hide();
    divs.eq(current).fadeIn("normal");
    console.log(divs.eq(current))
    if (current < divs.length - 1)
        current++;
    else
        current = 0;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards">1</div>
<div class="cards">2</div>
<div class="cards">3</div>
<div class="cards">4</div>
<div class="cards">5</div>
<div class="cards">6</div>
<div class="cards">7</div>
<div class="cards">8</div>
<div class="cards">9</div>
<div class="cards">10</div>
<div class="cards">11</div>
<div class="cards">12</div>
<div class="cards">13</div>
<div class="cards">14</div>
<div class="cards">15</div>
<div class="cards">16</div>
<div class="cards">17</div>
<div class="cards">18</div>
```

So how it's must works:

First 10 sec show div's from **1-8**
After 10 sec show items from **9-16**
And in the end show rest **2 div's**
But for this exmple i have 18, but this data will be dynamicaly, and i dont know how many div's i will have

Comment: Please include your html

Comment: for 10 seconds interval should be 10000... since it is milliseconds

Comment: @Rishab it's just for teting, i dont want to wait now 10 sec :D

Comment: Add HTML code please will help us out to understand in deep

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i add html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution:

```
var current = 0;
$(".cards").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    var divs = $(".cards").hide();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 8) {
        divs.eq(current).fadeIn("normal");
        console.log(divs.eq(current))
        if (current < divs.length) {
            i++;
            current = current + 1;
        } else  {
             i = 0;
             current = 0;
        }
    }

}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found:

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elements = $(".cards");
    var index = 0;

    var showNext = function (index) {
        if (index >= elements.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        console.log(index);
        elements.hide().slice(index, index + 8).show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            showNext(index + 8)
        }, 10000);
    }
    showNext(0);
});
```